# 2015: What am I missing to get a simple hit counter block by page?

Tags: blocks, views

I've tried every recommendation I can find; I've enabled statistics and advanced statistics and can see that hits are being counted. I can display lists by what nodes are the most hit, etc; but I just want to display the results for the given node I'm on. How can I do this? I suspect the solution is in using contextual filters for a view, but I can't get this working, either. Help appreciated.

Drupal 7.

Comment: who can see: admin or Anonymous users?

Comment: Perhaps this module will help? https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount It exposes its data to Views, I'm not sure whether the core statistics module does...

Comment: @tritof Since I want it to be a block, I should be able to customize its visibility any way I want. For me, I just want admins to see it.

Comment: @Beebee I've tried it; same problem: shows many pages, not just the one I'm on.

Comment: Have you tried using the contextual filter and/or setting up a relationship for the node's ID when constructing the view?

Comment: @Beebee I'm not sure how to do those things. Online pages are not clear/applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do it with contextual filters, so I guess I still don't understand things on that front. However, a custom block with just a couple lines of PHP did the trick. All directions from:

[How to get visitors count of a page created using views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48148/how-to-get-visitors-count-of-a-page-created-using-views)

As per that post, custom code was:

```
<?php
$path = $_GET['q'];
drupal_set_message($path);
$visits = db_query("SELECT count(*) FROM {accesslog} where path = :path", array(':path' => $path))->fetchField();
echo "Views: " . $visits;
?>
```